# Subprocess.Call fails "The System Cannot Find the File Specified"

Tags: python

I have a .exe file called Manipula that takes as its source a .msu file.  I can successfully run what I want through the command line like so:

```
"C:/Flow Check/Run Quick/Applications/Manipula.exe" "C:/Flow Check/Data Processing/BLAISE TO BLAISE.msu"
```

However, I cannot simulate this behavior in Python-- no matter what I use.  I have tried
`os.system` and `subprocess.call` and `subprocess.Popen`

If I run something like the following

```
p= subprocess.Popen("C:/Flow Check/Run Quick/Applications/Manipula.exe" "C:/Flow Check/Data Processing/BLAISE TO BLAISE.msu", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in p.stdout.readlines():
 print line,
retval = p.wait()
```

I get an error: `The System Cannot Find the File Specified.`  I've triple-checked, the file is clearly there because it works when I run the commandline.

When I add `shell=True` to subprocess.Popen a new error appears that there is no directory `C:/Flow`, I think because the shell has a hard time processing spaces... I just don't know what's going on.

When I do `os.system("C:/Flow Check/Run Quick/Applications/Manipula.exe" "C:/Flow Check/Data Processing/BLAISE TO BLAISE.msu")` nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify program and its arguments as list:

```
p = subprocess.Popen([
    "C:/Flow Check/Run Quick/Applications/Manipula.exe",
    "C:/Flow Check/Data Processing/BLAISE TO BLAISE.msu"],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Writing string literals serially merges the strings:

```
>>> "abc" "xyz"
'abcxyz'
```

Comment: I think this is doing something.  I see that `Manipula.exe` is running in the background, but it just hangs indefinitely.  Is there anyway yo get the actual program to popup, as it does from the command prompt?

Comment: @Parseltongue, Is there any message in the console?

Comment: @Parseltongue, What happend you specify `[r"C:\Flow Check\Run Quick\Applications\Manipula.exe", r"C:\Flow Check\Data Processing\BLAISE TO BLAISE.msu"]` instead. (Don't remove the leading `r`s)

Comment: Same thing, Manipula.exe runs in the background, and never kills itself.  If I run it from the command line, Manipula will run for three seconds, do the necessary processing, and end itself.

Comment: I can't figure it out... let me know if you can think of anything.  For the time being, I just put that command in a batch file, and I'm using subprocess.call to run the batch file.  Maybe spaces in the file name has something to do with it

Comment: Did you try `subprocess.call(["C:/Flow Check/Run Quick/Applications/Manipula.exe", "C:/Flow Check/Data Processing/BLAISE TO BLAISE.msu"])` ? (not specifying stdout, stderr)

Comment: @Parseltongue, Try this one: `subprocess.call(r'"C:\Flow Check\Run Quick\Applications\Manipula.exe" "C:\Flow Check\Data Processing\BLAISE TO BLAISE.msu"', shell=True)`

Comment: Also doesn't work, but for a different reason- it appears that, whenever `shell=True` the program just abruptly ends and Manipula.exe is never called.  When you do not specify `shell` Manipula.exe runs forever, and you have to manually break the program

Comment: You posted that you accepted this answer at 8:33 but in the comments, at 8:49 you admitted that you still were not able to find the file specified.... so why would you select it as true?

Comment: @SomeGuyOnAComputer, If you want let the OP see your message, notify OP by adding "@" + "Parseltongue" in your comment.

Answer (score 5):

You are not passing in two strings; you are passing in *one* string with no whitespace between. Python automatically concatenates adjacent strings with nothing but whitespace in between:

```
>>> "C:/Flow Check/Run Quick/Applications/Manipula.exe" "C:/Flow Check/Data Processing/BLAISE TO BLAISE.msu"
'C:/Flow Check/Run Quick/Applications/Manipula.exeC:/Flow Check/Data Processing/BLAISE TO BLAISE.msu'
```

Note how there is no space between `.exe` and `C:/Flow`.

Put the two strings in a list:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["C:/Flow Check/Run Quick/Applications/Manipula.exe", "C:/Flow Check/Data Processing/BLAISE TO BLAISE.msu"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Now `Popen()` will handle passing in correctly quoted strings to the underlying OS as one command.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  You and falsetru have essentially identical answers, so I regret having to accept just one.

Comment: Not a problem, that's the way of Stack Overflow. We compete to get you the best quality answers. :-)